# How Can I Update All Prices with jQuery and AJAX?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to create a dynamic table, that uses AJAX to pull in calculated prices from the Rails side for rental units. Each rental unit has price information, in JSON (/companies/:id/locations/:id/units/:id/price.json), that I am fetching.

My problem is within the function that sets the `text` for each unit. It appears that it is only fetching the JSON for the first unit, and all of the following prices after are set to the first unit

```
Request URL: /storage_companies/2/storage_locations/4/storage_units/10/price
{id: 10, monthly_cost: 7.25, total_price: 87}
```

[image]

In the `UnitController` I've set up a price method to output the price information in JSON:

```
def price
    respond_to do |format|
      format.json { render json: @storage_unit, methods: [:total_price], only: [:id, :monthly_cost, :total_price]}
    end
  end
```

and the route:

```
resources :companies do
   resources :locations do
     resources :units do
       member do
         get :price
       end
     end
   end
end
```

How can I refactor this to iterate through all of the `units` and set the `text`?

```
$(function(){
  var CompanyId = $('.storage_company').data('params-id');
  var LocationId = $('.select_location').data('params-id');
  var UnitId = $('.select_unit').data('params-id');

  $.getJSON(`/companies/${CompanyId}/locations/${LocationId}/units/${UnitId}/price`, callbackFuncWithData);

  function callbackFuncWithData(data){
    $(".monthly_estimated_price").text("$" + data.monthly_cost.toFixed(2));
    $(".total_estimated_price").text("$" + data.total_price.toFixed(2));
  };
});
```

### Update

```
$.getJSON("/prices", function(data){
    $.each(data, function (index, value) {
      var price = value;
      $(`.select_unit[data-params-id="${price.id}"]`).each(function(){
        $(".monthly_estimated_price").text("$" + price.monthly_cost);
        console.log(price)
      });
    });
  });
```

I think I'm almost there but still not fully understanding how to iterate and set these dynamically.
[image]

Comment: `CompanyId ` is only from the first matching `$('.storage_company')` in page. If you want request for each you need to loop over all instances and make request for each and apply response to instance. Or conversely...get all data in array once...and loop over data and match to corresponding element(s) in page

Comment: Conversely `$(selector).text()` sets same text to every matching element in page

Comment: @charlietfl I think preparing all of the data in an array once, and looping over the data to match to elements on the page is the best approach. Any examples around the web that I could make reference of?

Comment: Fairly easy to match unique identifier in data to same identifier in the main repeating elements  like `<div id="company_973">`

Comment: @charlietfl Thanks for the insight - I'll look around for something

Comment: @charlietfl I just put an Update section where I tried a different approach, but still got a little stuck. Let me know if you could provide anymore guidance, I feel like I'm in a circle for the past 8 hours

Comment: @charlietfl let me know if it's too high of a level of effort to explain and I can look for another way to approach, but hoping to learn a thing or two